# JqueryUI(accordion) effect cannot load after replacing with new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list that uses the accordion effect from JqueryUI.I am able to swap the content inside the list. However, once I swap the content, I lose all the Jquery styling effect.I have done some research on the forum and people said that I should  destroy and re-initialize the accordion once I swap the content .I have tried all some of methods but they do not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#accordion').accordion({collapsible: true,active:false,heightStyle: 'content',event: 'click hoverintent'});      
    $('body').on('click','#category a',function(){    
    var page =$(this).attr('href');
    var php =$('#accordion').load('../php/'+page+'.php');       
    return false;
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `accordion` plugin, it will style the contents within it by adding classes and other properties. But once you reload the contents within it, those styles are lost.

In the load callback, you need to reinitialize the accordion plugin

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: 'content',
    event: 'click hoverintent'
  });
  $('body').on('click', '#category a', function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    var php = $('#accordion').load('../php/' + page + '.php', function() {
      $('#accordion').accordion('destroy').accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: 'content',
        event: 'click hoverintent'
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```